# text field lose focus when double tap on IOS

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

I am having a problem actually when double tap a field in a visualforce page on salesforce1 running on IOS. The keyboard appear but no characters appear in the textbox. Its like it lose the focus, but the cursor mark still blink. Its very strange but very blocking for my client too. But when i try to simulate this on the standard pages, it work fine. The problem is not css either, because i removed all CSS on my field and try again same result. I tried using javascript to detect double tap and set focus again on the field, but no success.
Does anyone came across this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So far, i only got to know the reason for this behaviour. In fact, this arise because a VF run in an iframe in the salesforce1 app. If you try the same thing with the standard page, this doesn't arise. This have been explain in the salesforce known issues, where the culpit is IOS and not salesforce. Unfortunately, there is no fixe for now :(